# Install galera cluster without remove existing mariadb

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, galera, multi-master

I have to setup Galera cluster in one of my production servers.

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Existing mysql: maridb 10.1
```

While installing this cluster, its asking to remove the existing `mariadb-server-10.1`

How can I install this without remove anything?

Comment: Do you want two instances of MariaDB on a single server -- one standalone, one as part of a Cluster?  Or are you trying to set up all nodes of a Cluster on a single server?

Comment: I need a 2 node cluster and one more server for arbiter

Comment: Two node on a single server ?

Comment: I have totally 3 servers, 1 is master1, 2 is master2, 3 is arbiter

Comment: OK So your current production server is MariaDB 10.1 right ?

Comment: THis is new setup with 10.0

Answer (score 1):

If you installed MariaDB 10.1, you don't need to remove anything because MariaDB Server and MariaDB Galera Server packages have been combined and Galera packages and their dependencies get installed automatically when installing MariaDB 10.1.

So you must only configure galera without remove anything.

[Reference](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/getting-started-with-mariadb-galera-cluster/)

Comment: OK, I  tried 10.0 too, this is also asking to remove MariaDB-server :(

Comment: I said if you have already mariadb 10.1 just config it.That's it

Comment: Ok, that's fine, but I want to setup this on 10.0 also, that's why I'm asking.